# Advantages & Disadvantages of Using 'Salesforce Data' vs 'Data Extension' for Journey entry source

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm struggling to understand the use cases for these two entry source types.

Why not just always use Data Extensions?

Is there a huge latency difference between the two?

I've read people recommending using 'Salesforce Data' for a 'Welcome' journey because it will immediately add a new contact in Sales Cloud.

Can I not setup a 'Data Extension' to pull the new contacts as well and just run every 15 minutes?

Comment: It's a realtime vs batch conversation, I think. You can run every 15 mins (with hacks) and hope Salesforce doesn't charge you for overages on Automations at some point in the future when it suits them. It's up to your appetite for risk, I guess. From an architectural POV, I'm going with Salesforce Data and am living with the considerable limitations and the obvious get-outs Salesforce can do by saying "governor documented here" and deflections saying "you'll need to talk to 'Sales Cloud Support'.

Answer (score -1):

Sourcing the data from data extension instead of salesforce directly will always work. Journey doesn't actually care much about where the data is coming from as long as it has all the data points to refer in the journey activities and personalisation.

Below are some of the use cases where you may have to think of Salesforce Vs DE as a source of data for Journey.

Use case 1 - Not all customers would synchronise everything from salesforce to marketing cloud as every synch record will be part of the All contacts and is impacted from revenue point of view. Some customer even just does the connector set up and just push the data directly to journey when required, not having to synchronise the contact/leads to sfmc.

Use case 2 - Every time you create a salesforce event as an entry in SFMC, it will also create a supporting process builder in salesforce. I believe this is for every version of the journey. This is an additional load to the salesforce system.

Use case 3 - Not all customers will have exposure to both SFMC and salesforce to manage and configure the salesforce objects as an event source to journeys. This will also be a problem in long run from maintenance point of view.

Use case 4 - If journey has just one email, only 1 wave, then I suggest to go with the salesforce entry source. But if journey has multiwave communications over a period of time, its always best to use the DE as a source. Using DE for multiwave is more flexible to exit the customer when they meet goal.

Use case 5 - If there are exclusion lists that has to be worried about in SFMC, then DE is the way to go as it can be handled via SQL to exclude and push the target data to Journey.

Thanks,
Mano